# how to use verbatim inside Metapost

Tags: verbatim, metapost

I am trying to put verbatim text using minipage inside Metapost.
It seems working outside Metapost but not working inside.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{20em}
    \begin{Verbatim}
    sample text 1
    sample text 2   
    sample text 3
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}


\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1); 
draw (0,0)--(10,-10) ; 
label(btex
    \begin{minipage}[t]{20em}
        \begin{Verbatim}
        sample text 1
        sample text 2   
        sample text 3
        \end{Verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
etex,(30,-30));
endfig; 
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}

------------------------- the 2nd question ------------------------------
to meet the policy of site,  my previous message was relocated. 

Thanks Henri

I tried to use \verbbox as below without success yet. 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newbox\verbbox
\begin{document}

\setbox\verbbox=\vbox{\hsize=15cm
\begin{Verbatim}
    sample text 1
    sample text 2 sample text 21
    sample text 3 sample text 31  sample text 32 
\end{Verbatim}
}
before verbbox  \\
\box\verbbox  \\
after verbbox 

\begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1); 
    label(btex ~ etex, origin) ;    
    label(btex
    \begin{minipage}[t]{16cm}
    \box\verbbox
    \end{minipage}
    etex, (15,-15)) ; 

    drawarrow (0,0)--(30,-30) ; 
    endfig ; 
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use verbatim inside `mplibcode`. Instead you can save the verbatim material in a box and use the box inside.

Comment: Thank you Thruston .  I need to prepare reports time and time again which must show before and after. And with verbatim + metapost, I think I can save many lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SaveVerbatim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{exampleA}
sample text 1
sample text 2   
sample text 3
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1); 
draw (0,0)--(10,-10) ; 
label(btex \BUseVerbatim{exampleA} etex,(30,-30));
endfig; 
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

You can have as many `SaveVerbatim` as you want, with different names. With `\BUseVerbatim` you don't even need to guess the width.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do appreciate it.