# How to use minted inside metapost

Tags: minted, metapost, luamplib

When I try to use minted with metapost (using luamplib)

```tex
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(3);
    picture P;
    P = thelabel(btex \vbox{\begin{minted}{c++}
        int main() { return 0; } 
    \end{minted}} etex); 
    
    fill bbox P withcolor (1, 1, 31/32) draw P; draw bbox P;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
```

I get this error

```
! Argument of \FV@BeginScanning has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.38     \end{mplibcode}
```

How can I get rid of this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't (easily) put verbatim boxes inside an `mplibcode` environment, due mainly to the way the code is scanned.

Comment: You also have a missing `;` after the fill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one (admittedly rather cumbersome) way to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{minted}
\newbox\mintybox
\begin{document}
\setbox\mintybox=\vbox{\hsize=3in
\begin{minted}{c++}
   int main() { return 0; } 
\end{minted}
}
\[
\begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1); 
    picture P;
    P = thelabel(btex \box\mintybox etex, origin); 
    fill bbox P withcolor (1, 1, 31/32);
    draw P; 
    draw bbox P;
    endfig ; 
\end{mplibcode}
\]

\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex -shell-escape <yourfile.tex>` to get this:

[image]

*Note*: You need to make sure that the `\end{minted}` line is on its own, with nothing following it on the same line.

Comment: See also the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594484/how-to-use-verbatim-inside-metapost?rq=1)

Comment: thanks for the answer ! I am actually using your DrawingWithMetapost repo (full of useful examples btw), and I had tried to used minted instead of listings in one of your example.

Comment: Yes, I recognised my code in your example.  But that example was for plain `mpost` not for `luamplib`.

Comment: Do you think, it would be impossible to implement it in luamplib ?

Comment: It's on my (long) list of thing to investigate for https://github.com/thruston/Drawing-with-Metapost